# Can I connect a cloud of vertices with edges and faces?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]
Hi all. Thanks in advance.

I would like to experiment with geometry nodes and the shortest path capability. Can I create a mesh if I connect these vertices with edges and faces with GEONODES?

The verts were generated with the included landscape generator after I deleted edges and faces. I understand there will be limitations but let us move forward.

The ultimate goal is to track camera footage to mesh.

Comment: I would say: if it is a quadratic shape where the number of points along the X axis and Y axis are equal and evenly distributed, then it is possible.

Comment: Although I wrote an answer I am not sure if this will help you - because I have no experiences with track camera footage. The landscape generator creates a regular grid of points, but I have no idea how evenly distributed a point cloud by tracked footage will be... You mention shortest paths, but probably the shortest path is not always the correct path to connect complex geometry.

Comment: Good point. Camera trackers, essentially vertices, usually come in by the hundreds, which is a relatively low number in blender. The trouble is that the trackers could be a statue, or scale vertically up a wall - so there is a Z value. Shrinkwrap sounds like a nice option.

Comment: I imagine blender fluids are calculated as points, and then meshed, so blender has this capability somewhere. Maybe a metaball at each point and then a remesh.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of vertices in the X and Y direction are known in the base landscape, you can create a grid in geo nodes with the same number of vertices and setup their Z values equal to the landscape ones to obtain a proper mesh instead of a cloud of points.

Here is the result below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need this for landscape point clouds like shown in your question and they have an equal amount of vertices in X and Y direction, you can simply read out the total amount of vertices by getting the *Domain Size* > *Points*, calculate the square root and feed it into *Vertices X* and *Vertices Y* of a *Grid*. The size of the grid does not matter.

Then use the *Sample Index* node to get the positions of all vertices at their respective index and with a *Set Position* node all vertices of the grid are placed where the point cloud vertices are. By sampling the full position you can plug in landscapes in all sizes and varying amounts of vertices as long as they are the same in X and Y. Basically it does not even matter if the original point cloud is square or stretched in one direction or if all points are aligned in X and Y direction. Only for the simple square root operation it is necessary that the amount of vertices is the same in both directions.

[image: point cloud to grid]